# Error when running HardInfo in terminal?

Tags: command-line, error-handling

Every time I run HardInfo via terminal, I get this showing up in said terminal:

> sh: 1: /lib/libc.so.6: not found
>
> sh: 1: gnome-about: not found

Here is a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

It doesn't seemingly impede my ability to use the HardInfo GUI, and as you can see from the screenshot it definitely still appears. Still, when I see the words "not found", it makes me worry. xD

What's this all about? Is it anything to worry or be concerned about?

---

#### Specs

- **Make & Model**: Dell Inspiron N5010
- **Operating System**: Ubuntu 15.04
- **Terminal Used**: Terminal (Gnome-terminal), v3.14.2-0ubuntu3 [the default one included with Ubuntu 15.04]
- **HardInfo Version**: v0.5.1-1.4ubuntu1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first line has been reported as a bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/hardinfo/+bug/1473142

I'm guessing the second one relates to that bug, but to answer your question: No you shouldn't worry so long as the program works the way you expect it to.

Looking through the source code, 'gnome-about' is only referenced in a function that detects your desktop environment. If it still detects your desktop environment, I don't think it matters.